# Generate treeView from dot notation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I am writing an application using WPF MVVM  and I have an observable collection of items. 
Each item has a name of this type:

> [system].Test.Test3.Something.1
>
> > [system].Test. Test3.Something.2

I would like to create a tree-view from this dot notation and when i press for example on the node "1", to make it as selected-item of the tree View so i can use it with my Content Control.

I have done this but if i press on 1 for example, i don't get the SelectedItem

```
 private void addNode(string values)
    {
        var n = root;

        foreach (var val in values.Split('.'))
        {
            var isNew = true;

            foreach (var existingNode in n.Items)
            {
                if (((TreeViewItem)existingNode).Header.ToString() == val)
                {
                    n = (TreeViewItem)existingNode;
                    isNew = false;
                }
            }

            if (isNew)
            {
                var newNode = new TreeViewItem
                {
                    Header = val
                };

                n.Items.Add(newNode);

                n = newNode;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is part one of a good question.  Part two is to show us what you've done.  Part three is to tell us why it isn't working, including full exception details and other relevant information.

Comment: i have tried to do it in XAML but i ended up with the conclusion that it should be done in code-behind because of the " dot " and i am stuck now